# Not authorized to perform operation verify lock on repository

Tags: gerrit, git-lfs

I installed lfs plugin on gerrit server, but there are many error message on server.

```
ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.lfs.locks.LfsLocksContext : Not authorized to perform operation verify lock on repository
```

Does anybody know what this error means, and how to fix it? I attempted to google this error, but didn't find any results.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Gerrit LFS plugin stores the Git LFS file lock information at the following directory:

```
$GERRIT_SITE/data/lfs/lfs_locks
```

Have you changed this directory using the "locks.directory" option in the "$GERRIT_SITE/etc/lfs.config" file? Verify if everything is OK with this option and with this directory.

For more info, see the "Global Plugin Settings" section [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/lfs/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md).

Comment: No, I didn't change the default directory, but there is no lfs_locks folder in following directory:   `$GERRIT_SITE/data/lfs`

Comment: How to check the directory of saving lfs_locks on gerrit?

Comment: What about the owner/permission of the "data/lfs" directory? Can Gerrit user read/write on it?

Comment: Yes, gerrit account could read&write on data/lfs directory.